# Unusual amount of ARP who is on WLAN form unknown IP

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, arp

I am seeing a unusual amount of ARP traffic on my Wireless network. My wireless network is on the subnet 192.168.1.0/24 but the ARPs are coming from 10.215.0.1 which is not in my subnet. It is also asking for IPs on 10.215.0.1/12 network. What is this and how do I stop it?

[image: Arp requests]
[image: Source mac]

Comment: Does your router maybe have a device list where you can see how they're connected? You could check that. Perhaps change the network password.

Comment: Based on the list of devices as suggested by Daniel B - check if there are any IoT devices?

Comment: @DanielB I already checked and there are only 2 connected devices both of which are known to me. (I checked with the MAC). They are my 2 laptops.

Comment: @Darius Nope. There are only 2 laptops connected.